# Javascript: How to remove illegal URL characters from a file name?

Tags: javascript, regex

How to remove illegal URL characters from a file name but not the dot on file extension? Is there a way to do this? Currently I have this

```
fileName = "I am a file name + two.doc"
fileName.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9-_]/g, ''); // regex that removes illegal characters
```

But it also removes the . on the .doc I want something that will remove illegal characters except the file extension. Is it possible?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Add the `.` literal as well then, `\.`:

```
var fileName = "I am a file name + two.doc";
fileName.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9-_\.]/g, ''); // 'Iamafilenametwo.doc'
```

It's worth pointing out that the `.` character in a regular expression will match [any single character except the newline character](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions). Therefore you needed to escape the character in order for it to match the literal character, `\.`

Also, `\w` is equivilant to `[A-Za-z0-9_]`, therefore you could shorten your expression to:

```
/[^\w.]/g
```

And as [hwnd points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33771154/javascript-how-to-remove-illegal-url-characters-from-a-file-name/33771161#comment55309790_33771161), if you don't want to allow other dot characters inside the filename, you can use subtraction:

```
.replace(/(?!\.[^.]+$)\.|[^\w.]+/g, '')
```

Comment: Awesome, Thanks guys!

Answer (score 4):

For Windows filenames, I believe a simplified version of the .replace should be
`.replace(/[\\/:"*?<>|]/g, '')`

[image]  [image]