# Replace bad characters for file names

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a string like:

> "something | other thing / another thing"

But I need to remove all characters that can't be in a file name (like | or /) because I need to save a file with that string using node.

The real problem here is that I can't predict how this string is coming. I tried using some regex expressions that i found in internet but no success.

Comment: https://preview.npmjs.com/package/slugify

Comment: See also [Javascript: How to remove illegal URL characters from a file name?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33771154/215552)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [@Muhammad Ovi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5704816/muhammad-ovi) suggested, you could use some library to create a valid URI, in this case [Slugify](https://preview.npmjs.com/package/slugify) could get the job done.

Have a nice one.

Answer (score 1):

What characters are (or are not) legal in a file name or a file system path is entirely dependent upon your operating system and the underlying file system.

Assuming that you know the set of ***disallowed*** characters, it should be as simple as something like this:

```js
function cleanFileName( s ) {
  return s.replace( /[set-of-disallowed-characters-here]/g, '' );
}
```

or you could get fancier and do something like this:

```js
function cleanFileName( s ) {
  return s.replace( /[set-of-disallowed-characters-here]/g, '-' )
          .replace( /-+/g, '-' );
}
```

So if your set of disallowed characters contains the punctuation below, the above would turn this

```
abc!/~dev\|/foo
```

into

```
abc-dev-foo
```